# I use PySide2 in Pycharm to build my GUI program, but where can I find reference documentation?

Tags: python, pycharm, pyside2

When I use "Ctrl + Click" to view the explanation of a function, I cannot find any related documentation. Where can I find related documents?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt only provides the .pyi so that the editor can know the necessary classes, methods and types since PySide2 being a Qt wrapper is written in C++ so the python code is limited (almost non-existent) so documenting it with code is unnecessarily heavy, therefore to know the documentation you must use the official pages:

- https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/
- https://doc.qt.io

As PySide2 is a Qt wrapper you should expect that the C++ docs are also valid for Python, so in general in my experience the Qt documentation is generic so it is valid for any type of wrapper

Answer (score 0):

PySide2 is included in the Qt binding for Python (link to PyPi https://pypi.org/project/PySide2/). As PySide2 is part of the Qt framework, you can use the Qt documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/

Edit: Typo